# Tricky condition for PostgreSQL UPDATE query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, foreign-key, cascade

I need help with a PostgreSQL query.

I have a Django app + pg backend, where users post interesting URLs (or links) and can then comment under such links (called replies). There are two pg tables to represent this: *links_link* and *links_publicreply*.

I am to delete aged rows from *links_publicreply*. That's easy enough:

```
DELETE FROM links_publicreply WHERE "submitted_on" < now() - interval '7 days';
```

But some of these are referenced in the *links_link* table, hence the query fails. The reference in the `links_link` table is:

```
latest_reply = models.ForeignKey
    (
        'links.Publicreply', 
        blank=True, 
        null=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

My first question is: **How do I delete these foreign key references too**?

My hunch is:

```
begin;
UPDATE links_link SET latest_reply=NULL where latest_reply_id in 
    (SELECT id FROM links_publicreply where "submitted_on" < now() - interval '7 days');
DELETE FROM links_publicreply WHERE "submitted_on" < now() - interval '7 days';
commit;
```

Does this look right?

If you read the update query above closely, you'll notice it sets *latest_reply* to null wherever it pointed to an aged *links_publicreply* row.

I don't actually want to do that. I ideally want to set *latest_reply* to the next available *links_publicreply* record (associated to the particular `links_link` record), which didn't get deleted by the query:

```
DELETE FROM links_publicreply WHERE "submitted_on" < now() - interval '7 days';
```

**How do I do that?** That's my second question.

---

#### Tables

PG tables, as described in my Django app's **models.py**, are as follows:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reply_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    latest_reply = models.ForeignKey
        ('links.Publicreply', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Publicreply(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer_to = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `ON DELETE CASCADE` option to your foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE links_link 
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name,   
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (latest_reply_id)
      REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Apparently in django the above is translated as:

```
on_delete=models.CASCADE
```

Comment: in Django App he should use configure it within a model, or do extra migration

Comment: @MladenUzelac: If I do it the way Mihai recommends, wouldn't that work as well? Or do I **need** to do it within the model (or do a migration)? Do add how do add it to the model as an answer.

Comment: @HassanBaig I`m not familiar with python,but foreign constraint are a staple of dbs. why would you even use a framework for something that any db does native,probably a lot faster?

Comment: Mihai, I prefer it your way, but I might additionally need to update my Django model too, to sync with the change in the DB. Thus asking @MladenUzelac whether there's more to the answer than what you've provided.

Comment: I had one project with Django so I wasn't able to give you full answer immediately. And glad that my comment lead to a solution. Working with Django and migrations is elegant way to deal with DB.